# Continuous onto function preserves number of path-connected components

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $X = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y = 0\} \cup \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: -x+y = 1\}$. We want to prove that there is no continuous onto map
$$
A:=X \cup \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x=0\} \overset{f}{\longrightarrow} B:=X \cup \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y=1\}
$$
considering both $A$ and $B$ equipped with the Euclidean topology.

Our approach to the problem has been to remove the point $p = (0,1)$, which is the intersection of two lines, from the set of departure, and observe that this leaves $A \setminus \{p\}$ with three path-connected components. Then, regardless of where $f(p)$ lands in the codomain of the function, the number of connected components of $B \setminus \{f(p)\}$ is not preserved. Our main doubt is whether we can use this fact to prove that such a function $f$ does not exist. In other words, is the number of path-connected components preserved by a continuous and surjective function between topological spaces?

[image]

EDIT:
As mathcounterexamples.net has suggested in his answer, we cannot use the reasoning that $f$ preserves the number of path-connected components of $A$ and $B$. We are now wondering what other method of proof could we use to solve the problem. Could it be, maybe, something related to the fact that $A$ contains a closed path (triangle) and $B$ contains none? Thanks in advance for your help and answers.

Comment: I'm wondering if we could exploit the fact that $A$ and $B$ do not have the same number of intersection points. But that would be an injectivity property, while the map in only requested to be onto, so I have a doubt.

Comment: @Marc I would suggest that you create another question. Because there are in fact two distinct questions. The current one should be the one of the title and the second one to be opened the one with the specific $X$ and $f$ case.

Comment: It might also help if your pictures matched your formulas. Your $X$ contains the line $x+y=1$ which has slope $-1$, whereas your pictures show no line of slope $-1$ (assuming a standard $x,y$-coordinate system).

Comment: I agree with @mathcounterexamples.net. Since the question asked has a good answer, the best practice would be to accept a current answer and to post a new question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The number of (path)-connected components is indeed not preserved under a continuous subjective map.

Let's consider $f : X \to C$ where $X = \{(x,0) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x \in \mathbb R\}$, $C \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ is the circle of radius one centered on the origin and $f(x) = (\cos x, \sin x)$. $X$ and $C$ are connected.

$f$ is onto and continuous. However $X \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ has two (path)-connected components while $f[X \setminus \{(0,0)\}] = C$ has only one.

Answer (score 4):

There *is* a continuous onto map from $A$ to $B$, hence your conjecture can not hold.

Using your own picture:

[image]

Take any point $o$ ("origin") in $B$. Map all the yellow, green, blue parts of $A$ to $o$. We are left with mapping the semi-straight red line to $B$.

For that, split such red line in segments of unit length: $[a_0,a_1],[a_1,a_2], \ldots$, with $a_i \in A$. Map each interval $[a_i,a_{i+1}]$ to $B$ so to form a continuous path starting and ending at $o$, so that the path runs over each point in $B$ which is at most $i$ units distant from the origin $o$ (according to the Euclidean distance).

This is continuous, since it's the gluing of paths with the same endpoint. This is also onto since any point $B$ will be eventually run over by some path because its distance from $o$ is finite.

This seems to generalize to many other cases.

Comment: That’s a funny and clever construction !